# Can I detect a lack of a Console when running a Mono application in the background?

Tags: c#, mono

I have a .NET 4.5 console app which I'm running on CentOS using Mono. The code finishes with:

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

If I run the app interactively then it behaves as I'd expect, with the Console.ReadLine() waiting for keyboard input, however, if I run the app using nohup to run it in the background...

```
nohup mono Program.exe > Program.log &
```

then Program.log shows that the Console.ReadLine() causes an odd exception:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/home/user/[Unknown]" is denied.
  at System.IO.FileStream.ReadData (IntPtr handle, System.Byte[] buf, Int32 offset, Int32 count) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.FileStream.ReadInternal (System.Byte[] dest, Int32 offset, Int32 count) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.FileStream.Read (System.Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLine () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.UnexceptionalStreamReader.ReadLine () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.SynchronizedReader.ReadLine () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Console.ReadLine () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Program1.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I can obviously catch and quietly ignore the exception, but I was curious to know if it is possible to detect the fact that I have no Console and so change my application's behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of experimentation this appears to do the job for me:

```
if (Console.In is StreamReader) {
    Console.WriteLine("Interactive"); 
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Background"); 
}
```

Not sure if it's ideal for all possible stdin redirection and so on, but it works well enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at - [Environment.UserInteractive Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userinteractive.aspx) (which is also supported in mono - http://buttle.shangorilla.com/1.1/handlers/monodoc.ashx?link=P%3ASystem.Environment.UserInteractive)

> The UserInteractive property reports false for a Windows process or a
>   service like IIS that runs without a user interface. If this property
>   is false, do not display modal dialogs or message boxes because there
>   is no graphical user interface for the user to interact with.

Comment: I checked this out and was initially encouraged to see a False value returned from Environment.UserInteractive when running my application in the background. Sadly though I also get a False value when running interactively. Looking deeper; see https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System/Environment.cs and the comment on line 297 which reads '[MonoTODO ("Currently always returns false, regardless of interactive state")]'.

Comment: @Elliveny haven't looked into that. As it seems for now you should manually override the method with something like try catch. and return false in the catch block :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically what I usually want to know is:

- Is it running as a service or not
- Is it running as a console or not

I guess your question is about this as well... I'll just write down the recipe, because it took me way too long to figure all out all the details...

**Setting up your project**

The easiest way to do this is to create a `windows service` C# application, and start hacking in the `Program.cs`.

Basically what I do here is:

- If it's Mono, check if the TTY is attached -> Console, mono
- If it's Windows, check UserInteractive
- If it's interactive, allocate a console so that the thing works.
- If that doesn't work, we just assume a console application.

Here goes the code:

```
public static ProgramType ProgramType
{
    get
    {
        if (!programType.HasValue)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime") != null)
                {
                    // It's a console application if 'bool Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.isatty(0)' in Mono.Posix.dll
                    var monoPosix = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("Mono.Posix, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756");
                    Type syscallType = monoPosix.GetType("Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall");
                    var method = syscallType.GetMethod("isatty");
                    bool isatty = (bool)method.Invoke(null, new object[] { 0 });

                    if (isatty)
                    {
                        programType = ProgramType.MonoConsole;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        programType = ProgramType.MonoService;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Environment.UserInteractive)
                    {
                        programType = ProgramType.WindowsConsole;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        programType = ProgramType.WindowsService;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                programType = ProgramType.Unknown;
            }
        }
        return programType.Value;
    }
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool AllocConsole();

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool FreeConsole();

[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int lpdwProcessId);


/// <summary>
/// The main entry point for the application.
/// </summary>
static void Main()
{
    switch (ProgramType)
    {
        case ProgramType.WindowsConsole:
            {
                // WindowsConsole application
                //
                // Get a pointer to the forground window. The idea here is that
                // IF the user is starting our application from an existing console
                // shell, that shell will be the uppermost window. We'll get it
                // and attach to it

                IntPtr ptr = GetForegroundWindow();

                int u;
                GetWindowThreadProcessId(ptr, out u);

                try
                {
                    Process process = Process.GetProcessById(u);

                    if (process.ProcessName == "cmd")
                    {
                        // Is the uppermost window a cmd process?
                        AttachConsole(process.Id);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // No console AND we're in console mode ... create a new console.
                        AllocConsole();
                    }

                    // Console is now accessible.
                    NubiloSoft.Util.Logging.Sink.Console.Register();

                    // Arguments?

                    StartConsoleService();
                }
                finally
                {
                    FreeConsole();
                }
            }
            break;

        case ProgramType.MonoConsole:
            {
                // Console is now accessible.
                NubiloSoft.Util.Logging.Sink.Console.Register();

                // Arguments?
                StartConsoleService();
            }
            break;

        case ProgramType.MonoService:
        case ProgramType.WindowsService:
            {
                // Start service
                ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
                ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
                {
                    new Service1()
                };
                ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
            }
            break;

        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Unknown CLR detected. Running as console.");
            {
                // Console is now accessible.
                NubiloSoft.Util.Logging.Sink.Console.Register();

                // Arguments?
                StartConsoleService();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

I usually use the default Service1 to call 'Start' and 'Stop' on some static `Startup` class. It works the same with the `StartConsoleService`. Because the ProgramType is exposed, you can use it whenever you need it.